# Match on property types in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to match nodes in Neo4j/Cypher based on the type of a property value? I'm looking for something like this:

```
MATCH (n:Person)
WHERE NOT(n.id_number isa STRING)
RETURN n
```

The closest I can think of is

```
MATCH (n:Person)
WHERE NOT(n.id_number = toString(n.id_number))
RETURN n
```

Although this is still pretty fast, it doesn't use an index, according to PROFILE, whereas I think an `isa`-style query could use an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apoc.meta.type` procedure which returns type name of a value like INTEGER,FLOAT,STRING,BOOLEAN,RELATIONSHIP,NODE,PATH,NULL,UNKNOWN,MAP,LIST.

Ref: https://community.neo4j.com/t/data-type-of-a-property/1309/2

Comment: Thanks user3382968! I added a bit of extra data to the answer and accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your workaround, Cypher has no way to match nodes by property value type.